# Best way to store URLs in App.Config or AppSettings.json

Tags: c#, console-application

I find myself writing lots of URL app settings in C#. Often I just store them like `SomreURL`, but then other times I go with separate Scheme, Host and Path parts.

Does anyone have a best practice for how they handle URLs in settings files and how they deal with missing slashes and the like?

Comment: I disagree that this is opinion based. I think a suitable answer would show how other people would have solved this problem in the past. I believe in the shoulders of giants idea. I think when people Google, finding this question would help them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class has some ways of helping you craft URLs.

Assuming you store Scheme, Host, and Path parts separately, you can do something like:

```
string scheme = "https://", host = "stackoverflow.com", path = "questions/44707782/best-way-to-store-urls-in-app-config-or-appsettings-json";
var base = new Uri(String.Concat(scheme, host));
var uri = new Uri(base, relative);
```

I like to have a static `Settings` class:

```
public static class Settings
{
     public static string Scheme => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Scheme"];
     public static string Host => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
     public static string Path => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"];
     public static Uri BaseUri => new Uri(String.Concat(Scheme, Host));
     public static Uri SomeUri => new Uri(BaseUri, Path);
}
```

One way to validate your settings is to have a method called Validate on your Settings class that attempts to use one of the Uris

```
public static void Validate()
{
    var valid = SomeUri; // will throw exception if not valid Uri
}
```

Then from your startup class:

```
Settings.Validate();
```

Comment: I dislike this method.  The `Uri` class can deconstruct/parse a full url.  Storing the full url requires a single AppSettings entry, and reduces the chance of entry error as it allows you to copy/paste from a browser location bar.  As with anything, actual use cases should dictate design.  There are legitimate cases where having the pieces separated would be more useful.

Comment: Yeah I'm not too keen as well on storing Uri parts in configuration unless there's an explicit need to do so (maybe swapping between http and https in dev vs prod). My answer is more about using a settings class so you can process and validate the settings if you need to.

Comment: Yes.  The settings class is a good idea.